Create bulk operations to Azure AD B2C to type Local Account
I'm trying to import users to AD B2C from a csv file using the bulk operations but it is giving me an error because the user doesn't have the same domain as the tenant:

Request was unsuccessful. Details: The domain portion of the userPrincipalName property is invalid. You must use one of the verified domain names in your organization.

The users have the domains: @gmail.com, @company.com, @hotmail.com, etc.
I have 3 B2C tenants that I need to import these users respectively: dev.onmicrosoft.com, uat.onmicrosoft.com and prd.onmicrosoft.com
But if I try to create an user from the csf file manually, I can succeed by selecting the Create Azure AD B2C user option:

How can I import users from a csv file using Bulk Operations on AD B2C using different domain? On csv file template has no option to say that the user is an AD B2C user.

That's because when you create a B2C user manually, e.g. peteg@gmail.com as the username, the UPN is something like:
ba698781-34b8-4ee5-8e93-07254711111@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
So, if you want to bulk import, the UPN in the CSV file must be one of the valid domains in that tenant.
You can't add the email in the csv. You can add it manually to the email attribute, but you can't sign in with that email address. You have to use the UPN to sign in.
The user is Local by default.
To add the email as a sign-in, you would have to do a bulk invite but then they won't be Local users.
Otherwise, you can add email as a sign-in by adding it to the user Identity array via Graph, e.g.
"identities": [
  {
    "signInType": "userName",
    "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    "issuerAssignedId": "johnsmith"
  },
  {
    "signInType": "emailAddress",
    "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    "issuerAssignedId": "jsmith@yahoo.com"
  },
  {
    "signInType": "federated",
    "issuer": "facebook.com",
    "issuerAssignedId": "5eecb0cd"
  }
]


Ok, I can change the csv file to use peteg_gmail.com@tenant.onmicrosoft.com as UPN. But where I can put the peteg@gmail.com to be used as email and the type as Local Acount on csv file? I can't find this columns.

I'm using singInType emailAddress via Graph. How can I use this way via Bulk?

Have a look at this code sample that does bulk imports - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations#code-sample-how-to-programmatically-manage-user-accounts

I already use Graph to create users from inside my application. The question is that now I need to import the users already created on another Idp(WSO2) that use the email to sign in. I would need a bulk import to AD B2C users.
